# VSIX how to order my classifier provider in respect to other installed extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I developed a toy vsix extension. It implements a classifier for F# source files. 
In the meantime the guys from FSharp Power Tools upgraded their extension to offer syntax highlighting for F# files.

Now in VS 2013 my classifier is always run before theirs, and consequently they are overriding my coloring.

Is there a way to order a classifier on respect to another? I did not find any info about this by googling.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.  Classification is a form of tagging and tagging is unordered in Visual Studio.  The editor simply runs an import for all tagging implementations and essentially defaults to MEF import for ordering.

Many hooks in Visual Studio can be ordered by using the `[Order]` attribute.  This is typically listed as part of the documentation on MSDN.  It is not for classification / tagging and I checked the implementation to make sure it wasn't an oversight (it wasn't).

Comment: If it is so, it is very unfortunate...Could you please hint me the assembly and location where the classifiers are invoked?

Comment: I found how to do it in my case. Your answer is correct in general, there is no way to order more than 2 classifiers.

Comment: ...if the first  one has Priority.Default.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

In my case **Priority.Low** has to be specified as Order attribute for the classes that implement **ClassificationFormatDefinition**.

Actually this solutions works only for **2 classifiers**.
FSharp Power Tools has the Order(After = Priority.Default)
My classifier will be invoked after FSharp Power Tools when After = Priority.Low.

```
[Export(typeof(EditorFormatDefinition))]
[ClassificationType(ClassificationTypeNames = "FSharpNumberClassifier")]
[Name("FSharpNumberClassifier")]
[UserVisible(true)] //this should be visible to the end user
[Order(After = Priority.Low)] 
internal sealed class FSharpNumberClassifierFormat : ClassificationFormatDefinition
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've encountered similar problem. My VSIX extension colorized DSL statements in code via regular expressions. The problem was with the comments in code - it didn't avoid them and writing logic which would analyze all comment-related cases and produce correct tags was quite a lot of work, too much actually. So I've come up with an idea - may be I can rearrange the order of coloring for my coloring to be done before comments and preprocessor instructions. Then these colors will override my incorrect coloring.

I've already googled Order attribute but it didn't work in my case because as far as I remember I couldn't place my classification type in the correct place, it either overrided comments coloring or was overriden by some other default coloring. All I needed was to increase priority of comments and preprocessor definitions to make them override my coloring. It's a hacky decision but it worked for me.

So I've ended up with a following solution. In a class wich initializes yours classification formats (in my case it is tagger provider) I added IClassificationFormatMapService service via MEF. Also I already had IClassificationTypeRegistryService service to get IClassificationType objects

```
[Import]
internal IClassificationFormatMapService classificationFormatMapService = null; 

[Import]
internal IClassificationTypeRegistryService classificationRegistry = null;
```

For the names of predefined classification types you will need Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.StandardClassification nuget package.
Then you should add using directive to your file

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.StandardClassification;
```

Then I used a following code fragment:

```
private static void IncreaseCommentFormatTypesPrioirity(IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry, IClassificationFormatMapService formatMapService,                                                                  
IClassificationType myType)
{
   IClassificationFormatMap formatMap = formatMapService.GetClassificationFormatMap(category: "text");
   IncreaseServiceFormatPriority(formatMap, registry, PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.ExcludedCode, myType);
   IncreaseServiceFormatPriority(formatMap, registry, PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.Comment, myType);
}

private static void IncreaseServiceFormatPriority(IClassificationFormatMap formatMap, IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry, string formatName, IClassificationType myType)
{
    IClassificationType predefinedClassificationType = registry.GetClassificationType(formatName);
    IClassificationType artificialClassType = registry.CreateTransientClassificationType(predefinedClassificationType);
    TextFormattingRunProperties properties = formatMap.GetExplicitTextProperties(predefinedClassificationType);

    formatMap.AddExplicitTextProperties(artificialClassType, properties, myType);
    formatMap.SwapPriorities(artificialClassType, predefinedClassificationType);
    formatMap.SwapPriorities(myType, predefinedClassificationType);
}
```

It works for me. It's an experimental code and there is a lack of documentation on transient classification types and classififcation order, so I'm not 100% (even 90%) sure that it does all things right and doesn't break something in VS.

But, after all you can change the classification order at runtime (although you cannot tell the exact position explicitly, you have to use SwapPriorities method which will change places of two formats)

Comment: Can you give more context of where you called the `IncreaseCommentFormatTypesPrioirity` method in your provider? Can you add the snippet of code of the provider class?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that context now as I have completely changed my own classifier. If I remember correctly I called it in the implementation of `IViewTaggerProvider` in a `CreateTagger` method as a part of my own initialization routine. Like I said in my answer - this is completely experimental and unverified, I would advice against it in the production code.

Comment: The documentation states that those methods are exactly for doing what you expect. To swap priority of the two IClassificationTypes.

Comment: Yes, the method works as documentation says. I said it is risky because I doubt it is a good idea to swap priority of the existing widely used classification type like comments. You can get unexpected coloring for comments.